# Pentaho reports displays without Data

Tags: report, pentaho

I have already posted similar question earlier but did not get any response yet so thought let me describe it in detail here.

I am upgrading pentaho reporting from 3.6.1 to 3.8.2. all reports were working fine in 3.6.1 version with my spring based web application.

apart from upgrading necessary jars from 3.8.2, I have opened my existing reports in 3.8.2, save it again and previewed them. all reports worked fine in 3.8.2 report designer and I can able to see reports with data.

so I replaced related .prpt files in my application and tried to run reports from it. but now reports are displaying with out data. Please let me know if anyone has any insight.

Comment: Is there an error in the pentaho.log? In the shell that the server was run from? In catalina.out ?

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the Pentaho forum:

Here is an usefull link for Pentaho http://pentahoasksumeet.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue like you, I embedded reporting engine with my Vaadin Java Web Application, and got reports with no data after upgrading reporting engine.

My problem was that, I didn't match the exact same version of the libraries in the SDK with the Pentaho Report Designer. **Just be sure to be using the same version of the SDK and the Report Designer**, and the problem will dissapear.

The issue comes frequently with the datasource definition between the different versions. If your reports are in old versions, upgrade them using Report Designer and saving them again. Don't use older or newer versions of the reports with the SDK either with the Report Designer. Match the exact versions.